# How to save a datastream in mp3 format?

Tags: qt, mp3, qt-creator, qt5, qdatastream

I am receiving an mp3 file in packets over network and want to save them in mp3 format on my computer. I am programming in C++ and using Qt Creator as IDE.

To be more specific, I am storing the received data in a QDataStream object which is automatically writing to the file it is connected to...
Do I need any encoding or should I just name the file MyMusic.mp3 and that was it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are receiving a mp3 file you can just rename it with a ".mp3" at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you are receiving is an MP3, then it has already been encoded in that format. You just need to write it out to a file that has the extension .mp3